# Dynamic android string resources

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to get string resources from a repository (like `HashTable`, `List` etc. ) not strings.xml?
Desired usage in layouts like

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@StringRepository.GetMessage("Search")"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>
```

My challenge is maintain string values on application server (web) and refresh all string resources (both layout and java side) without version updating.

I tried to traverse all Views on `onCreate` method of `Activity` instance, but couldn't find a solution for dynamically created Views.

Any help to achieve this challenge would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The `@resource` syntax only works with XML defined resources. If you want to define your strings in a hashmap, you will need to set the hint/text of your views in code.