# Android string hashcode by device

Tags: android, hashcode

Is it possible to get different hashcode from same string on different devices? (i got only one device so i can't test it) Or android sdk get same int value from same string on different devices? (I already have a case on .net compact fw and .net fw returns different hashcode for same string)

For example:

```
int hash = "Enter text".hashCode();

hash == 123445564 on Samsung S3
hash == -16644335 on HTC Desire
```

Comment: Codes are equal on several devices I could check. But there is absolutely no warranty that it will be in this way always. One day you app may be launched on device that has different `hashCode()` implementations for `String`.

Comment: While all devices should produce the same value (because they use the same Java implementation) you should consider using MD5 or anything that has guarantees about the outcome of a hash. `hashCode()` is just a random internal number that is AFAIK only guaranteed to stay the same during runtime of your app, anything beyond is unspecified.

Comment: Thanks @zapl, i'll consider to use MD5. but i think that generating md5 is more time consuming than generating hashcode. If there is no noticeable differece, i'll gonna use md5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the hash function remains the same (as far as I know it remains the same in different SDK versions) the result should be the same.

However, if you are getting the strings from `strings.xml` and you have localized versions of string, then you may get different hashs for the same `getString(R.string.mystring)`

Regards,
Luis

Comment: Thanks @Luis, i mean on same string, not from android resources. I'll craft it for challenge on my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364033/dynamic-android-string-resources